# Play files with double click instead single click in playlist of VLC

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, playlists

There is any option to change this behavior?

I'm using VLC in Kubuntu.

Comment: The behavior depends on the file manager (Dolphin), not on any software associated with a file type. So, it's at the file manager settings that you can change it.

Comment: It works for me. This is the answer I was looking for. How did you figure it out? I been looking for info about this and didn't found anything useful.

Comment: You were probably looking in the wrong places / wrong search words. And knowing single-click to open is the default in Kubuntu or any other KDE distro it was kinda obvious.

Comment: You're right. I didn't suspect that.I'm very new with linux. Thanks for your time.